# White blank screen on android while running react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Here is my project folder [Project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGjD9.jpg)

Everything worked fine and good when i first launched project into my device.
I wanted to learn react navigation so I followed this link https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android 
After installing react-native navigation and tried to make a startup screen as my splash screen in my

> screens folder

Index.android.js

```
import App from './src/App';
```

index.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import startupscreen from './startupscreen';

export function registerScreens() {
   Navigation.registerComponent('dudenew.startupscreen', () => 
 startupscreen);
}
```

App.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
 AppRegistry,
 } from 'react-native';

 import { registerScreens } from './screens';

 registerScreens();


 AppRegistry.registerComponent('dudenew', () => dudenew);
```

startupscreen.js

```
import React , { Component }  from 'react';
 import{
    Text,
  Image,
  View,
  StyleSheet,

 } from 'react-native';


 export default class startupscreen extends Component{
render(){

    return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>

            <View style = {styles.logotext}>

                <Text>
                    <Text>Hellooo  </Text>
                    <Text style = {{color: 'blue'}}> hh </Text>
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>

    );
}
  }
       const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container : {
                  flex : 1,
            backgroundColor : 'blue'

},
logotext : {
    alignItems : 'center',
    flexGrow : 1,
    justifyContent:'center'

    }
    });
```

Why is it showing me white blank screen ? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find the answer? if so please write the solution down here

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with react-native version, downgrade your react-native version to 0.49, then it should be fine.